# spring MVC errors : Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I want to pagination in Spring MVC but getting error :
Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface . Anyone can help? thanks!

Comment: Please show the offending code. What are you trying to do? Why should spring need to instantiate a `Pageable`?

Comment: Actually I want pagination my website, everything working fine, but when i Using PagingAndSortingRepository in Spring I got this error . If you know how to paging , please tell me

Comment: Show the code please.

Answer (score 8):

To resolve `Pageable` parameters, Spring MVC uses a component called a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`(reference [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/invocation/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html)). Specifically for Pageable as parameter, HandlerMethodArgumentResolver used is `org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, this can be registered using Java Configuration by just adding the `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` annotation.

More options are available here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web

Comment: thanks for your help, after setting i got error :Could not autowire field: com.repo.ListRepo
Error creating bean with name 'listController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
No qualifying bean of type [com.repo.ListRepo] found for dependency . Maybe i config wrong some where, please help me